# Bubble Sort Algorithm in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int list [50];
void bsort(int list[], int n);
void printArray(int list[], int n);

int main ()
{
    for (int i = 100; i > 50; i--)
    {
        list[i] = i;
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }
    int n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
    bsort(list, n);
    printArray(list, n);

  return 0;
}

void bsort(int list[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i <= 48; i++)
        {
            for (j = i+1; j <= 49; j++)
            {
                int temp;
                if (list[i] > list[j])
                {
                    temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list [j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
}
void printArray(int list[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << list[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

I'm in an intro-level computer science course and I am currently trying to write a program that calls the function 'bsort' to arrange the elements of the array 'list' in increasing order but my output is 49 zeros and I am not sure why? My professor wanted us to initialize the array 'list' starting at 100 and ending with 51 (in decreasing order).

Answer (score 1):

Your initialisation loop is incorrect. Try like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    list[i] = 100 - i;
    cout << list[i] << endl;
}
```

Your version did `list[100] = 100, list[99] = 99, etc` but the array only has size 50.